# How to compute the PDF of a sum of a discrete and a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable

I have a problem with this exercise in probability and statistics:
Calculate the probability density function (PDF) of 
$$Z=X+Y$$
where $Y$ is discrete random variable which is equal to $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability;
$X$ is a standard gaussian random variable independent of $Y$.

I know that the PDF of the sum of two continuous independent variables is given by the convolution of the marginal PDFs
$$f_z(z)=f_x*f_y,$$
but if one of the two variables is discrete what should I do?

Comment: If you prefer to obtain convolutions directly through PDFs, rather than by means of some clever equivalent approach, it can easily be done in terms of [distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) (in the Schwartzian sense, *not* in the probabilistic sense of the word!). For instance, the *Mathematica* expression `Integrate[ 
 PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]][
     x - y] (DiracDelta[# + 1] + DiracDelta[# - 1])/2 &[
  y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` returns the correct answer.

Comment: The [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/295363/15941) has been asked by the OP, and an answer already accepted, over on math.SE

Comment: Closed as off topic due to cross-posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition the density in the following way:
$$
p_Z(z)=\sum_{i \in \{-1,1\}}  p_Z(z|Y=i)P(Y=i)
$$
with $p_Z$ being the density function of $Z=X+Y$.
Does this help you? If you have further difficulties feel free to ask, but since this is an exercise...

Comment: What do you mean for pz(z|Y=i) in the summation? is it conditioning Pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Without giving too much away, one way to start thinking about this might be to think about what the conditional distributions $P(Z|Y=1)$ and $P(Z|Y=-1)$ look like.

Now see if you can remember an expression for calculating $P(Z)$ in terms of $P(Z|Y)$ and you should be there.